# How to add a hovering effect to my navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My navbar does not show a hovering effect. I have added the following CSS code but it doesn't work.

```css
container a:hover {
  color: #555;
  z-index: -10;
  animation: fill 1s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: fill 1s forwards;
  -moz-animation: fill 1s forwards;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

What should I do?

Here is my CSS/HTML code:

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Arial;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  padding: 5px; 
}

.container a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="whole-div">
  <div class="container">
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
    <div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <a href="#section1">Toehold Switch</a>
          <a href="#section2">Interlab</a>
          <a href="#section3">Charaterization</a>
          <a href="#section4">Program</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why dont you add ```!important``` in your CSS and then try

Comment: Did you put body tag inside div?

Comment: @chiller No I did't

Comment: @Ashish sah What do you mean ?

Comment: Did you create keyframe animation with the name fill ? the one u used here `animation: fill 1s forwards;`

Comment: I mean to say try using ```color: #555 !important;
z-index: -10 !important;```

Comment: Looks like you forgot the period in the CSS declaration? Should be `.container a:hover {}`

Comment: You have a `<body>` tag incorrectly placed between the divs. All the divs should be descendants of the `<body>` element.

Comment: Only `<li>` elements (and script supporting elements) are allowed as direct children of `<ul>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the period in your class declaration. When I add a period to it, it looks like it works fine. Try it out and let me know what happens.

```css
.container a:hover {
  color: #555;
  z-index: -10;
  animation: fill 1s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: fill 1s forwards;
  -moz-animation: fill 1s forwards;
  opacity: 1;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Arial;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  padding: 5px; 
}

.container a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="whole-div">
  <div class="container">
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
    <div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <a href="#section1">Toehold Switch</a>
          <a href="#section2">Interlab</a>
          <a href="#section3">Charaterization</a>
          <a href="#section4">Program</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey your code is okay but you may be forget to add a dot of your container class in CSS (at the first line).

```css
/* you have missed a dot at the first line user   .container a:hover   instead of   container a:hover   in your CSS */

.container a:hover {
  color: #555;
  z-index: -10;
  animation: fill 1s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: fill 1s forwards;
  -moz-animation: fill 1s forwards;
  opacity: 1;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Arial;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  padding: 5px; 
}

.container a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="whole-div">
  <div class="container">
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

      <div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <a href="#section1">Toehold Switch</a>
            <a href="#section2">Interlab</a>
            <a href="#section3">Charaterization</a>
            <a href="#section4">Program</a>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error I noticed is in your first CSS code you forgot `.` to designate that you are targeting class `container`.

[image: hover over image]

Also have a look the snippet code below:

```css
.container a:hover {
  background-color: green;
  z-index: -10;
  animation: fill 1s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: fill 1s forwards;
  -moz-animation: fill 1s forwards;
  opacity: 1;
}
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-family: Arial;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  padding: 5px; 
}

.container a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="whole-div">
  <div class="container">
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

      <div id="myHover">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <a href="#section1">Toehold Switch</a>
            <a href="#section2">Interlab</a>
            <a href="#section3">Charaterization</a>
            <a href="#section4">Program</a>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**You might play around with the code to make it more awesome by online code editor like [this](http://codepen.io).**

Comment: It's absolutely clear that he's trying to `a:hover`. `.container:hover` makes not much sense to me.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan OP wants the anchor tag `a` to have a hover style. They want that hover to apply only to anchor tags within elements with a class of `container`.

Comment: @blackandorangecat are you talking to me? That's exactly my statement.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes - I tagged you in the comment

Comment: @blackandorangecat so? That's exactly what I said. - if you take a closer look at the [edit] history you'll notice that Moh did `.container:hover` - and BTW the exact same was already answered by Summon...